# runTarget missing or invalid - on GWT Maven project

Tags: gwt, maven

When trying to run our GWT app from maven command line, I get the following error:

The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:run are missing or invalid.

However, this is with the following in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.5.0</version> 2.1.0-1 -->
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>com.magick.webtrader/Webtrader.html</runTarget>
                    <buildOutputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</buildOutputDirectory>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/gwt</generateDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                    <copyWebApp>true</copyWebApp>
                    <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>

            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to nest those `<Configuration>` elements i.e. `<Configuration>` inside another `<Configuration>`. Try fixing this and see if it works. On a side note, you shouldn't need to specify parameters like `<buildOutputDirectory>` explicitly if you're anyway using the default values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse and m2e - open the pom file in the pom editor and it will indicate the errors in your POM.xml.

One such error is in your **`Conifugration`** tag. Ensure that you drop your extra configuration tag.

Also always check your pom.xml w.r.t to sample ones from GWT team -

1) [Validation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/validation)

2) [Dynatablerf](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/dynatablerf)

3) [Mobilewebapp](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/mobilewebapp)